# Blackletter fonts supporting long s and r rotunda?

Tags: typography, history, blackletter

I'm doing up a document in the style of the [earliest printed documents](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incunable).  For this, I need to find a blackletter font that supports [long s « **ſ** »](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_s) and [r rotunda « **ꝛ** »](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R_rotunda).

Are there any such fonts out there?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The long s '**ſ**' can be found in many blackletter fonts, but the r rotunda '**ꝛ**' seems to be very rare. There are several blackletter fonts by Peter Wiegel (Cat Fonts) that contain both glyphs and are for free:

- Rotunda Pommerania
- Berthold Mainzer Frkatur UNZ1A
- Blankenburg UNZ1A
- Fette UNZ Fraktur
- Schwaben UNZ1A

Of these, *Rotunda Pommerania* comes closest to the blackletter type used in that incunable in Wikipedia. It's called *rotunda* (German: Rundgotisch – 'round Gothic'). However, Pommerania doesn't seem to have a standard 's'. You should also refer to the ReadMe files for infos on input (e.g. type '&' for the 'ꝛ'), since the fonts are not in OTF.

Download page: http://www.fontspace.com/peter-wiegel

Both characters are also in:

- UnifrakturCook
- UnifrakturMaguntia

(They are also featured by Google Webfonts.) Download page: http://unifraktur.sourceforge.net

More blackletter fonts featuring the r rotunda are downloadable via Peter Wiegel's own website: http://www.peter-wiegel.de/fonts2.html